# How To Read Lines of CSV or Text File, Loop Over Each Line and Save To a New File For Each Line Read

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, readlines

I have a unique problem that I thought I had solved until I hit the wall with using While Loop to control the flow of this program.

Synopsis:

I have a flat file (CSV or text) that has some URLs that I want to scrape, append a new tag to the HTML using BeautifulSoup (which worked) and then save each scraped URL to a new file name.

What I Need:

1. Iterate over each line
2. Fetch the URL
3. Scrape the page of each URL
4. Append new HTML tag
5. Save the file, using the name of the HTML file if possible
6. Restart the same program again where it goes to the next line.

I'm very sure this has to do with me being unable to understand the basics, I'm still trying to wrap my head around this. Here's my code:

What's Wrong:

Using Python3, the code actually works, I used Jupyter to watch the code line by line and a series of print statements to see what get's returned when the While Loop runs.

The problem is that only one file is saved and URL at the end of the file is the only thing saved. The other URLs are scraped.

How do you get each line iterated and scrape to save uniquely before going to the next line? Am I using these constructs incorrectly?

URLs:

https://www.imgacademy.com/media/headline/img-academy-alumna-jacqueline-bendrick-ready-tee-against-men-golfbc-championship

https://www.imgacademy.com/media/headline/img-academy-u19-girls-win-fysa-state-cup-u19-championship

https://www.imgacademy.com/media/headline/img-academy-celebrates-largest-commencement-ceremony-date-200-ascenders-earn

Code:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

filename = 'urls.csv'

with open(filename, 'r+') as file:


    while True:

        line = file.readline()

        user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0'

        headers = {'User-Agent':user_agent}

        response = requests.get(line, headers)

        print(response)

        soup = BS(response.content, 'html.parser')

        html = soup

        title = soup.find('title')
        meta = soup.new_tag('meta')
        meta['name'] = "robots"
        meta['content'] = "noindex, nofollow"
        title.insert_after(meta)

        for i 
        with open('{}'".txt".format("line"), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            outf.write(str(html))

            if (line) == 0:
                break
```

Comment: Okay, so I solved this my self. What I needed was a for loop that used an index and enumerate function to make sure the loop ran, ran the code/scraping and then an adjusted with open procedure that sliced the variable (take the http stuff away and save the real file name) and thus saving the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = 'urls.csv'

with open(filename, 'r+') as file:

    #line = line.replace('\n', '')

    print(line)

    for index, line  in enumerate(file):

        user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0'

        headers = {'User-Agent':user_agent}

        print(headers)

        response = requests.get(line, headers)

        print(response)

        soup = BS(response.content, 'html.parser')

        html = soup

        title = soup.find('title')
        meta = soup.new_tag('meta')
        meta['name'] = "robots"
        meta['content'] = "noindex, nofollow"
        title.insert_after(meta)

        with open('{}.html'.format(line[41:]), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(str(html))
```

Comment: 'r+' is the wrong file mode. The `print(line)` in line 7 will lead to a `NameError` because `line` is undefined at that point. `enumerate()` doesn't make sense because `index` isn't used anywhere. Having the names `soup` and `html` for the same object makes the code harder to follow.

Comment: The program did run for me actually did quite well, however, I'll try your suggestions.